# Сериализация: паттерн composite

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, компоновщик

Как нужно записывать в xml-файл объекты класса?
Я сделал это так, но при добавлении листа (Leaf) появляется исключение:

> InvalidOperationException: Тип TreeS.Leaf не ожидался. Используйте атрибут XmlInclude или SoapInclude для задания типов, которые не известны как статические.

Что нужно исправить?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TreeS
{
    public abstract class Question
    {
        [XmlElement("Question")]
        public string name;

        public Question()
        {

        }
        public Question(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public abstract void Display();
        public abstract void Add(Question c);
        public abstract void Remove(Question c);
        public virtual void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    public class Answer : Question
    {
        [XmlArray("Question1"), XmlArrayItem("Leaf")]
        private List<Question> children = new List<Question>();

        public List<Question> GetChildren { get => children; }

        public Answer()
        {

        }

        public Answer(string name)
            : base(name)
        {

        }

        public override void Add(Question component)
        {
            children.Add(component);
        }

        public override void Remove(Question component)
        {
            children.Remove(component);
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            foreach (Question component in children)
            {
                component.Display();
            }
        }
        public override void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вопрос: " + name);
            if (children.Count != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ответы:");
                for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
                {
                    children[i].Print();
                }
                Console.WriteLine('\n');
            }
        }
    }

    public class Leaf : Question
    {
        public Leaf()
        {

        }
        public Leaf(string name)
            : base(name)
        {
        }
        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        public override void Add(Question component)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Remove(Question component)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Question question = new Answer("123");
            Question question1 = new Answer("5");
            Question answer = new Leaf("qwe");
            Question answer1 = new Answer("asd");

            question.Add(question1);
            question.Add(answer);
            question.Add(answer1);
            question1.Add(answer);

            question.Print();

            CreateXML("tree.xml", question);
            Answer question2 = GetXML("tree.xml");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void CreateXML(string filename, Question question)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, question);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, question);
            writer.Close();
        }
        private static Answer GetXML(string filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            Answer collection;
            collection = (Answer)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

            return collection;
        }
    }
}
```

Делал по примеру [Компоновщик](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/4.4.php)

Comment: Если уж залили простыню, то опишите сущности, их предназначение и ожидаемые результаты при отработке клиентского кода. А то вижу вопрос и наследующиеся от него ответ и лист дерева, что есть что и зачем - не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы (де)сериализация заработала, нужно сделать то, что сказано в описании ошибки. Добавляем атрибуты `XmlInclude`:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Answer))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Leaf))]
public abstract class Question
```

Благодаря им сериализатор знает, какие классы-потомки могут оказаться вместо базового класса.

---

Оставим в стороне иерархию ваших классов (с какой стати *ответ* наследует от *вопроса*?), поговорим о коде сериализации.

В метод `CreateXML` передаётся тип `Question`, а сериализатор создаётся для типа `Answer`. Но ведь там может оказаться и `Leaf`.

Из метода `GetXML` возвращается тип `Answer` - это явно подогнано под тип сериализатора в предыдущем методе. Явные нарушения логики работы.

---

Не меняя логику ваших методов, просто перепишу их, чтобы сделать более устойчивыми к возможным исключениям.

```
private static void CreateXML(string filename, Question question)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer));
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, question);
    }
}

private static Answer GetXML(string filename)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Answer answer = (Answer)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

У вас зачем-то делается сериализация в `StringWriter`.
И почему имя локальной переменной `collection`?

Comment: Единственное что, можно ещё создавать сериалайзер так: `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Answer), new[] { typeof(Answer), typeof(Leaf) });` - без задания атрибутов. Но это уже кому как угодно.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan - я бы на вашем месте написал ответ про такое создание сериализатора. Комментарии не всегда читают.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, хм, полезно. Не знал о наличии такого конструктора.